# Unauthorized Access Exception error in OneDrive Business in PHP

Tags: php, sharepoint, onedrive

I'm try to create folder in OneDrive for Business account. And its gives me **Error**:

> {"error":{"code":"-2147024891,
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do
>   not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}

**[API document link](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm):**

After registering in Azure Active Directory it gives permission to all app access:

[image]

And after getting token and serviceEndPointUri  I'm try to create folder bout it's give error **UnauthorizedAccessException**.

I'm also trying to get the details of the user's OneDrive for Business, it **give me  the same error:**

```
GET {serviceEndPointUri}/drive
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

PHP code for get the details of the user's OneDrive for Business:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);      
$headers[0] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $get_access_token;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
```

> {"error":{"code":"-2147024891,
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do
>   not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}

**I'm using free subscription is the reason, it  give me an error: 
Unauthorized Access Exception**

**Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.**

Comment: do you have registered you app https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm#register-your-app-for-onedrive-for-business ?

Comment: i follow all run and register app to Azure :  https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm

Comment: look here https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm#sign-into-onedrive-for-business

Comment: @Eugen : yes im follow  it and getting token and serviceEndPointUri. but in step 5 its give me error {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}} or try to create folder.

Comment: have a look here https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/480

Comment: Can you provide the value of `serviceEndPointUri`? Feel free to replace the tenant name with something else, but keep `-my` if it's there alone with everything in the path. A `SPRequestGuid` value from the response headers for a failing request, along with the `Date` value, would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this myself.      Turn off the sharepoint, office software and webapps for the user at the license level.
Sign in as user,  sign out.
Turn them back on.
Sign in as user, sign out.
Wait 30 minutes.

Fixed.